# As a master's student, will a GRA or GTA position provide a greater benefit for PhD applications?

Tags: application, teaching-assistant, research-assistantship

I am a Master's student with goals to pursue a PhD. I am currently a graduate research assistant (GRA), but have been offered a GTA (graduate teaching assistant) position in Machine Learning. The course in question is challenging and is probably considered more competitive/desirable than most other GTA positions.

Which is better in terms of PhD applications? Also, is it considered better to have both GTA and GRA experience? I am asking for a generalization. How would you view this on an applicants resume? Let's assume average performance in both positions.

Comment: I took a stab at editing the question, perhaps it will get reopened. I removed the part about what employers want -- that's a question for Workplace.SE (though I imagine the answer will be similar).

Comment: Though, very related / possible duplicate: [Is TA-ing worth the opportunity cost (of having more time for research)?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/134440/is-ta-ing-worth-the-opportunity-cost)

Answer (score 2):

If you're planning to go into Academia, you might want to do a GTA (Graduate Teaching Assistantship) to get teaching experience. Because a GTA means approximately 20 hours per week on teaching duties, you may find it harder to work on your thesis or dissertation as much as you want.

A GRA (Graduate Research Assistantship) will focus on research instead but you may not be working directly on your thesis research but instead on another project for which a professor has funding.

At my university (25 years ago), a GTA paid less than a GRA so that's also something to check.